# Redirect from within a React.Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react.Component that has a form for a user to signin.

How can I redirect the app to a new page on successfull signin?

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import {Header} from  './layout/Header.js';

export class Signin extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

 handleSubmit(e){
  history.push('/dash');
 }
 render() {
   return (// markup)
 }
}
```

I'm using the Router in App.js to display pages in my app, eg signin and dash.

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/signin">
          <Signin />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/dash">
          <Dash />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
</Router>
```

I get the error "history is undefined"

If i try @MoiioM 's method - I get the error:
Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: I don't see it defined anywhere. Where do you expect it to be coming from?

Comment: @BrianThompson - Open to suggestions!  : )  I found lots of different answers accross the web/SO/docs none of which worked - maybe due to versions, context, my errors etc.

Comment: The problem is just that you have to get `history` from react router in some way, it doesn't just become globally accessible. There are several options - within functional components using the `useHistory` hook, in a class component using the `withRouter` HOC, using either type by defining your routes using the [`component`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) or [`render`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) prop. These are how you gain access to `history`. If you have a further issue (like a syntax error with `withRouter`) please post that context to the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Yes I was expecting the answer to be how to get at history - not that it would be global.    So i'd very much like to stick with the classes rather than functional components, so I need to use withRouter - the trouble is there is always an error however I try.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-withrouter-ey4yw. It does work. If you need help with your syntax error you'll need to post what you've tried so we can replicate it.

Comment: In that example - they get withRouter from react-router-dom not react-router.  Is that significant?

Comment: Also, that demo does not use the line export { withRouter(Signin) as Signin }; which is what is giving the error

Comment: I've updated the sandbox to include the export. You apparently can't call a function when aliasing. Use a temp variable.

Comment: It works! Thanks very very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the HOC (Higher-Order Component) withRouter on your class, then use the props history.

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import {Header} from  './layout/Header.js';

class Signin extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

 handleSubmit(e){
  this.props.history.push('/dash');
 }
 render() {
   return (// markup)
 }
}

//export { withRouter(Signin) as Signin }; // does not work, 

// @brian-thompsons suggestion:
const SigninWrapper = withRouter(Signin);
export { SigninWrapper as Signin };
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made this change, but I now get TypeError: this.props.history is undefined

Comment: are you using withRouter on your Signin class ?

Comment: Yes? I'm importing it as above in my question

Comment: If I add export { withRouter(Signin) as Signin }; to the bottom as per your answer, i get Unexpected token, expected "," (141:19)

Comment: Did you remove the `export` from the class declaration line?

Comment: I have updated the question to show more context

Comment: I have updated the answer with @BrianThompson 's fix. thanks guys.